# How to map collection of floats using Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class that contains a collection (IList) of floats that I'm trying to map in FNH:

```
class WeeklyHours {
    public virtual Person Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual WeekOfYear Week { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<float> DailyHours { get; set; }
}
```

The `DailyHours` member is initialized to a fixed length of 7 elements, one for each day of the corresponding week.

How do I map `DailyHours` in FNH?  I would like to keep everything in the `"WeeklyHours"` table rather than create an `"Hours"` table and a one-to-many relationship.

I can't use a set or bag because order is important (day of the week).

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why list and not array?

```
public virtual float[] DailyHours { get; private set; }

public WeeklyHours()
{
     DailyHours = new float[7];
}


Map(x => x.DailyHours);
```

this would create a binary represantation of the array in a column of the WeeklyHours-table.

Edit: another option would be a CustomUserType to serialize/deserialize the array to the column. I can post a mapping if wanted

Comment: Have you done this - mapping an array of floats directly? I'm using FNH 1.0.0.629, and that version required an IList.  Earlier versions of FNH had problems with mapping collections of value types - IIRC, those problems were fixed in this release.  What version are you using?

Comment: i have mapped arrays of ints and doubles in production code. I used FNH 1.1 and 1.2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fluent NHibernate automapping, this should just work, with no need for any additional help from the programmer.